# Search an array of elements in the lookup data

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an observable array in javascript,

```
lookups.Data
[...]
    __proto__: []
    length: 2884
    [0]: {...}
    [1]: {...}
    [2]: {...}
    [3]: {...}
    [4]: {...}
    [5]: {...}
    [6]: {...}
    [7]: {...}
    [8]: {...}
    [9]: {...}
    [10]: {...}
```

Each of record is like,

```
lookups.Data[0]
{...}
    __proto__: {...}
    BookName: "Silapathikaram"
    Author: "Illangovadigal"
    type: "Tamil"
```

I have one array of `someBooks` value,

```
someBooks = ["ABC", "CED", "Silapathikaram"]
```

Now I need to remove books from someBooks which are not in the lookup data.

If it is a single array, and single item I can use indexof like,

```
lookup.indexOf(book) == -1 // to check the existance of the book in the lookup
```

Can anyone suggest me is there any efficient or simple way to do this? Any help would be very useful.

Comment: Your somebook is incorrect format

Comment: Also when you say observable array, are you talking about Knockout's ObservableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to use a set. Build a set of all book names and find the intersection of the names and `someBooks`.

```
let allNames = new Set(lookups.Data.map(e => e.BookName)),
    someBooks = new Set(["ABC", "CED", "Silapathikaram"]);

let intersection = new Set();
for (var elem of allNames) {
    if (someBooks.has(elem)) {
        intersection.add(elem);
    }
}
```

Performing `.includes` on the entire list of book names multiple times would be slow and inefficient, while using a set should not have this problem, but ultimately it depends on the implementation of the browser.

Comment: @Rajesh Be patient, an example is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function and in the condition [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function.

```js
const someBooks = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
const lookup = ['A', 'C'];

const filteredBooks = someBooks.filter(book => lookup.includes(book));

console.log(filteredBooks);
```

Comment: Not sure if we need to cover observable array part.

Answer (score 1):

In order to filter values from somebooks which aren't present in `lookups.Data` array, you could make use of `filter` and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function

```
var newbooks = someBooks.filter(value => {
    return lookups.Data.some(data => data.BookName === value)
})
```